# Any ideas on how to solve this integral $\sin ax / (x^2+b^2)^2$?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, derivatives, complex-integration, residue-calculus

I've been trying to find the value of the following integral using the residue theorem :
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin ax\ dx}{(x^2+b^2)^2}$$

So basically the idea that I had is to transform this integral and to make it in the numerator as
$e^{iaz} = \cos az\ + i\sin az\ $  and thus
$$\mathrm{Im}\, \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{iaz}dz}{(z^2+b^2)^2},
 = \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin az\ dz}{(z^2+b^2)^2}$$

However in class we've only established the residue formula from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ , and when I try to integrate it that way (as in from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$) I obtain $0$ obviously because the function is odd.

- I'd like to add that I worked on a similair integral
  $\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos ax\ dx}{(x^2+b^2)^2}$ , using the poles $+ib$ and $-ib$, hence $(x^2+b^2)^2$ $=$ $(x+ib)^2(x-ib)^2$ and then calculating the $Res( \frac{\cos az\ dz}{(z^2+b^2)^2}, +ib)$ by using this :
  $$\mathrm{Re}\, \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{iaz}dz}{(z^2+b^2)^2},
   = \int_0^\infty \frac{\cos az\ dz}{(z^2+b^2)^2}$$

I'm trying to do a similar thing with the sin function. calculating the cos integral was way easier due to the fact that the integrated is even.

Any help is welcome to direct me in the right path. Also apologies since english isn't my first language!

Comment: The integral from $0 to \infty$ equals zero ?

Comment: Try $\displaystyle\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\vert\sin(az)\vert\ dz}{(z^{2} + b^{2})^{2}}$. Note that the integrand is even.

Comment: Hi Joshua, I have corrected that mistake thank you. I'll try solving it this way

Comment: Should I still use this  $e^{iaz} = \cos az\ + i\sin az\ $ ?, since we've got the absolute value now

Comment: That was a mistake from my part: the integral from minus infinity to infinity is. I read that in the question and got fixed in my mind....deleting.

Comment: That's okay, thank you though

Comment: @JoshuaWang: $|\sin(az)|$ is not analytic, so the Residue Theorem won't apply. The result from that integral will not give the integral that the question asks for.

Comment: Mathematica says that the integral is $$\frac{\sqrt{\pi}a|b|G_{1,3}^{2,1}\left(\begin{array}{c}\frac12\\ \frac12,\frac32,0\\ \end{array}\middle|\frac{a^2b^2}4\right)}{2b^4|a|}$$ where $G$ is the [Meijer G function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meijer_G-function). I don't think there is a simple derivation for this.

Comment: I have never heard/studied the Meijer G function so I didn't understand your answer, did you use the Residue theorem though?

Comment: Also, both a and b are positive numbers, I forgot to mention that above

Comment: @mathsbegineer77: I did not compute this myself. I used Mathematica to see if the integral had a simple form. I don't think it does.

Comment: Oh okay! Maybe my teacher made a mistake somewhere in the integral since we usually work with ones that are "easy" to solve

Comment: If that was given by a teacher, then I think there may be a typo. $\cos$ instead of $\sin$ gives a relatively easy integral.

Comment: @robjohn, well, why not compute the cosine integral and differentiate with respect to $a$?

Comment: @mjw: $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}a}\cos(ax)=-\color{#C00}{x}\sin(ax)$

Comment: As in do an integration by parts in the cosine integral? if I do that I would have a more harder integral to deal with

Comment: @robjohn,  understood.  Thanks!